# Send Email to Admin when Message size limit exceeded

Tags: centos, email-server, exim

How to trigger an email to admin, when someone tried to send an email exceeding the message size limit? I couldn't find any such configuration to tweak.

Note : I use exim MTA

Comment: Which MTA are you using?

Comment: I use Exim. I added the tag. Let me also add in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `exim.conf`, field `log_selector`, use [size_reject](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-log_files.html) to log the information in the log files if message rejected because size was too big, restart exim.
Create a script to parse the log file and if matched, send email(s), add to cron, done.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that via special router, transport and script.

First you have to add the router that measure the size of message:

```
slimit:
   driver          = accept
   condition       = ${if >{$message_size}{1M}}
   transport       = size_warning
   unseen
```

Place that router at the beginning of router section

Then add the transport anywhere at the transports section:

```
size_warning:
   driver          = pipe
   user            = mailnull
   command         = /some/script.sh $local_part@$domain $message_size
```

Here `/some/script.sh` contains the next code:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat << EOT | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: MAIL SERVICE <postmaster@$( hostname )>
To: user@domain.tld
Subject: Big message detected
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

User $1 receive message $2 bytes big!
EOT
exit 0
####
```